# Find the values of the positive integers $n$ such that: $\frac{(-\sqrt{3}+2)^{n+1}+(\sqrt{3}+2)^{n+1}}{4n+3}$ is positive integer

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

My question is as follow:

Find the values of the positive integers $n$ such that:

$$\frac{(-\sqrt{3}+2)^{n+1}+(\sqrt{3}+2)^{n+1}}{4n+3}$$ is positive integer.

I can see that for $n=1$ (among some other numbers) the condition is verified. However, I cannot go further with this procedure.

Comment: It might be easier to use the recursion, rather than the irrational numbers.  I think it is $A_{k+1}=4A_k-A_{k-1}$.  Look at the remainders $\pmod{4n+3}$, find values of $k$ when $A_k=0\pmod{4n+3}$.  There may be a pattern.

Comment: @Michael: I have tried that recurrence. There is no patterns.

Comment: Hint:
$(-\sqrt{3}+2)=(\sqrt{3}+2)^{-1}$

Comment: If $4n+3$ is a prime greater than $7$, we have to check if $\xi^{\frac{p-1}{4}}+\bar{\xi}^{\frac{p-1}{4}}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, where $\xi\in\mathbb{F}_p$ (if $3$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$) or $\xi\in\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. Since $\xi\bar{\xi}=1$, this is equivalent to $\xi^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=-1.$

Comment: @Mihail: Yes, I have used that fact. It seems that I am circuling in a closed curve.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Can you elaborate with you comment.

Comment: @DER: I bet it is extremely difficult to find such $n$s because even assuming that $4n+3$ is a prime for which $3$ is a quadratic residue, the divisibility condition depends on the Legendre symbol for $2+\sqrt{3}$. So, it is extremely likely that an infinite number of such $n$s exist (by searching them among suitable primes), but to compute every suitable $n$ looks really, really hard.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: **...the divisibility condition depends on the Legendre symbol for..**. Can you give to me a link for this fact.

Comment: @DER: $$\left(\frac{\xi}{p}\right)=\xi^{\frac{p-1}{2}}.$$ I assumed $p=4n+3$ and $\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=1$, so that $\xi=2+\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{F}_p$. Notice that: $$\xi^{\frac{p-1}{4}}+\xi^{\frac{1-p}{4}}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$ is equivalent to: $$\xi^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod{p}.$$

Comment: @daniel: I accept the nice idea.

Comment: @daniel: This is related to an abstract dynamical system problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I have changed the problem; I don't know whether it helps.  It is a bit big to fit into a comment.
The numerator is $$2\sum_k{n+1\choose2k}2^{n+1-2k}3^k$$
Multiply each term by by $(4n+4)^k=1\pmod{4n+3}$ and get
$$2^{n+2}\sum_k{n+1\choose2k}(3n+3)^k\\=2^{n+2}\sum_k{n+1\choose2k}(-n)^k\pmod{4n+3}\\
=2^{n+2}\Re(1+i\sqrt{n})^{n+1}$$

Comment: These terms are $0\pmod{4n+3}$ if the original numerators are $0\pmod{4n+3}$.  I have added and subtracted multiples of $4n+3$.  I don't think this is the answer, but hoped it might lead somewhere.